web3js@2 How can i call getFeeForMessage?
I am trying to call the rpc function getFeeForMessage but i cant figure out what to pass into the function:

  // What do I need to do here? 

  // Doesnt work: Argument of type 'LegacyCompiledTransactionMessage' is not assignable to parameter of type 'TransactionMessageBytesBase64'.
  // Type 'LegacyCompiledTransactionMessage' is not assignable to type 'string'.
  var compiledTransaction = compileTransactionMessage(
    budgetedTransactionMessage
  );
  // Doesnt work: Argument of type 'Buffer' is not assignable to parameter of type 'TransactionMessageBytesBase64'.
  // Type 'Buffer' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2345) 
  var serialized = serialize(compiledTransaction);

  // Using budgetedTransactionMessage Argument of type 'TransactionMessageWithBlockhashLifetime & ITransactionMessageWithFeePayerSigner<string, TransactionSigner<string>> & Omit<...>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'TransactionMessageBytesBase64'.
  // Type 'TransactionMessageWithBlockhashLifetime & ITransactionMessageWithFeePayerSigner<string, TransactionSigner<string>> & Omit<...>' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2345)
  const transactionCost = await rpc
    .getFeeForMessage(budgetedTransactionMessage)
    .send();

Full source:
import {
  airdropFactory,
  appendTransactionMessageInstructions,
  compileTransactionMessage,
  createSolanaRpc,
  createSolanaRpcSubscriptions,
  createTransactionMessage,
  devnet,
  generateKeyPairSigner,
  getComputeUnitEstimateForTransactionMessageFactory,
  getSignatureFromTransaction,
  lamports,
  pipe,
  prependTransactionMessageInstructions,
  sendAndConfirmTransactionFactory,
  setTransactionMessageFeePayerSigner,
  setTransactionMessageLifetimeUsingBlockhash,
  signTransactionMessageWithSigners,
} from "@solana/web3.js";
import {
  getSetComputeUnitLimitInstruction,
  getSetComputeUnitPriceInstruction,
} from "@solana-program/compute-budget";
import { getAddMemoInstruction } from "@solana-program/memo";
import { serialize } from "v8";

async function writeMemo(message: string) {
  // Create an RPC.
  const CLUSTER = "devnet";
  const rpc = createSolanaRpc(devnet(`https://api.${CLUSTER}.solana.com`));
  const rpcSubscriptions = createSolanaRpcSubscriptions(
    devnet(`wss://api.${CLUSTER}.solana.com`)
  );

  // Create an airdrop function.
  const airdrop = airdropFactory({ rpc, rpcSubscriptions });

  // Create a utility that estimates a transaction message's compute consumption.
  const getComputeUnitEstimate =
    getComputeUnitEstimateForTransactionMessageFactory({ rpc });

  // Create a transaction sending function.
  const sendAndConfirmTransaction = sendAndConfirmTransactionFactory({
    rpc,
    rpcSubscriptions,
  });

  // Create and fund an account.
  const keypairSigner = await generateKeyPairSigner();
  console.log("Created an account with address", keypairSigner.address);
  console.log("Requesting airdrop");
  await airdrop({
    commitment: "confirmed",
    lamports: lamports(1000_000n),
    recipientAddress: keypairSigner.address,
  });
  console.log("Airdrop confirmed");

  // Create a memo transaction.
  console.log("Creating a memo transaction");
  const { value: latestBlockhash } = await rpc.getLatestBlockhash().send();
  const transactionMessage = pipe(
    createTransactionMessage({ version: "legacy" }),
    (m) => setTransactionMessageFeePayerSigner(keypairSigner, m),
    (m) => setTransactionMessageLifetimeUsingBlockhash(latestBlockhash, m),
    (m) =>
      appendTransactionMessageInstructions(
        [
          getSetComputeUnitPriceInstruction({ microLamports: 5000n }),
          getAddMemoInstruction({ memo: message }),
        ],
        m
      )
  );

  // Figure out how many compute units to budget for this transaction
  // so that you can right-size the compute budget to maximize the
  // chance that it will be selected for inclusion into a block.
  console.log("Estimating the compute consumption of the transaction");
  const estimatedComputeUnits = await getComputeUnitEstimate(
    transactionMessage
  );
  console.log(
    `Transaction is estimated to consume ${estimatedComputeUnits} compute units`
  );

  const budgetedTransactionMessage = prependTransactionMessageInstructions(
    [getSetComputeUnitLimitInstruction({ units: estimatedComputeUnits })],
    transactionMessage
  );
  
  // What do I need to do here? 

  // Doesnt work: Argument of type 'LegacyCompiledTransactionMessage' is not assignable to parameter of type 'TransactionMessageBytesBase64'.
  // Type 'LegacyCompiledTransactionMessage' is not assignable to type 'string'.
  var compiledTransaction = compileTransactionMessage(
    budgetedTransactionMessage
  );
  // Doesnt work: Argument of type 'Buffer' is not assignable to parameter of type 'TransactionMessageBytesBase64'.
  // Type 'Buffer' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2345) 
  var serialized = serialize(compiledTransaction);

  // Using budgetedTransactionMessage Argument of type 'TransactionMessageWithBlockhashLifetime & ITransactionMessageWithFeePayerSigner<string, TransactionSigner<string>> & Omit<...>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'TransactionMessageBytesBase64'.
  // Type 'TransactionMessageWithBlockhashLifetime & ITransactionMessageWithFeePayerSigner<string, TransactionSigner<string>> & Omit<...>' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2345)
  const transactionCost = await rpc
    .getFeeForMessage(budgetedTransactionMessage)
    .send();

  // Sign and send the transaction.
  console.log("Signing and sending the transaction");
  const signedTx = await signTransactionMessageWithSigners(
    budgetedTransactionMessage
  );
  const signature = getSignatureFromTransaction(signedTx);
  console.log(
    "Sending transaction https://explorer.solana.com/tx/" +
      signature +
      "/?cluster=" +
      CLUSTER
  );
  await sendAndConfirmTransaction(signedTx, { commitment: "confirmed" });
  console.log("Transaction confirmed");
}

writeMemo("Hello, Solana!");


The getFeeForMessage() method requires the transaction message as a base64 string representation of the message bytes themselves. You can use the following transforms to produce that.
const base64EncodedMessage = pipe(
    // Start with the message you want the fee for.
    budgetedTransactionMessage,

    // Compile it.
    compileTransactionMessage,

    // Convert the compiled message into a byte array.
    getCompiledTransactionMessageEncoder().encode,

    // Encode that byte array as a base64 string.
    getBase64Decoder().decode,
) as TransactionMessageBytesBase64;

// Send the RPC request to get the fee.
const { value: lamports } = await rpc
    .getFeeForMessage(base64EncodedMessage)
    .send();

console.log("Message fee, in Lamports", lamports);

If you already have a compiled Transaction, you can obtain the bytes from it directly.
const base64EncodedMessage = getBase64Decoder().decode(
    signedTx.messageBytes,
) as TransactionMessageBytesBase64;

I would agree that having to cast from string to TransactionMessageBytesBase64 is a bit unintuitive. We would welcome helper methods that did this, as pull requests to @solana/transaction-messages
